# Solr filter query for suggester

Tags: solr, lucene, autosuggest, spelling, search-suggestion

I'm using the Solr Suggester Component, and was wondering, if the results can be filtered by the `fq` parameter. I have a query like this:

```
http://localhost:8982/solr/core1/suggest?q=shirts&fq=category_id%3A321&wt=json&indent=true&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.build=true
```

Here, I try to get some suggestions for `q=shirts`. I want to filter this by `fq=category_id:321`, so that I don't get suggestions from other categories. Because category with the `category_id:321` doesn't have any products related to `shirts`, it shouldn't return any suggestions. But it does. And when trying to search for that suggestion, it doesn't find anything, because the "original" search is filtered with the `fq=...` parameters.

I found something with `collate` here http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#spellcheck.collate. It collates my results, but also returns suggestions for `shirts`.

So my question is, is the Suggester (or basically the SpellCheckerComponent) aware of the fq parameter, and how can I use this parameter to filter the suggestions (or in a later stage, the spelling corrections).

**EDIT**

I found out, that the "normal" spellcheck component (e.g. with the class `solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker` for example), does indeed take the `fq` parameter into account. I can set

```
   <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
   <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">false</str>
```

and a suggestion for `shitr` is not returned when filtering by a certain category id, where the keyword `shirt` is not present.

I'm wondering, why this doesn't work with the suggest component. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think so, you need to look at this a bit differently to understand why. As you may already know, the SpellChecker operates based on dictionary built from the field you specified in the config.

default
  text
  solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker
  ...

And the copy fields that should makeup your dictionary during indexing fill the "text" field hence the dictionary.
 Example :

At this point spell checker does not know where the suggestion came from.

So with collation you can do little better, did you try &spellcheck=true&spellcheck.extendedResults=true&spellcheck.collate=true  ? This will make sure suggestion has some results .

The spellcheck.extendedResults ,Provide additional information about the suggestion, such as the frequency (hits) in the index, which may help you in your logic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does the `extendedResults` value take the `fq` value into account? Let's say, I filter my query by category 1, the suggester return some values, but the `extendedResults` field says, no there aren't any values for your current query?